# Totalprice column

Tags: sql

Is it possible to create a `totalprice` column in a table which gets its answer from multiplying 2 values from 2 different tables?

e.g

**orderquantity**

```
order_id | product_code | quantity
```

**ordertotalprice**

```
order_id | customer_id | totalprice
```

**products**

```
product_Code | product_name | product_desc | productcost
```

I want the `totalprice` column to be = `productcost*quantity`

Comment: which **database** you are using.

Comment: Your question is very vague.  What database are you using?  What do you want the output to look like?  Do you want to modify the table or just select results?  You mention two tables in the question, but appear to have columns for three tables listed.  What are the names of the tables?

Comment: so basicly is it possible to multiply the quantiy by the product cost and have it in the totalyprice column?

Comment: You would create a VIEW to add the derived column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query the totals per order:

```
SELECT orderquantity.order_id,
       SUM(products.productcost * orderquantity.quantity) AS total
FROM orderquantity
INNER JOIN products ON products.product_code = orderquantity.product_code
GROUP BY orderquantity.order_id
```

Wrap this query in an `UPDATE` statement to update column `totalprice` in table `ordertotalprice`:

```
UPDATE ordertotalprice
SET totalprice = grouped.total
FROM (
    SELECT orderquantity.order_id,
           SUM(products.productcost * orderquantity.quantity) AS total
    FROM orderquantity
    INNER JOIN products ON products.product_code = orderquantity.product_code
    GROUP BY orderquantity.order_id
) AS grouped
WHERE ordertotalprice.order_id = grouped.order_id
```

I am assuming here table `ordertotalprice` already contains the necessary records. If that is not the case, then you will need an `INSERT` statement instead of an `UPDATE`. But then I wonder where to get the `customer_id` from.